# Modifying machine code during execution in a managed environment

Tags: c++, unmanaged, managed-c++

I am attempting to use an unmanaged library from managed code. The unmanaged library modifies machine code in memory during execution, like a debugger. When I use it without any managed code it works. I have written a managed C++ class library that calls unmanged code that calls the unmanaged library. I do not get an error but execution proceeds as if the unmanaged library did not modify the machine code.

It makes sense to me that the managed code is using some protection that prevents the machine code from being modified, even though the machine code is being modified by unmanged code. If it is then I don't know what it is so of course I do not know how to turn it off. I have tried to find something relevant in the documentation but the documentation is too vague for me to be sure it is relevant.

Can anyone at least provide guidance of whether my theory is relevant?

Comment: Besides permission problems, the managed code might use other caches that are not flushed by your unmanaged library.

Comment: What part of the machine code are you trying to change? The managed app does not run directly on the machine but rather is a virtual machine. If you are trying to change the managed code then you have other options (Reflection.Emit). If you are trying to change the unmanged part then I;m not sure you can know where in memory the unmanged part is loaded exactly.

Comment: Sebastian, I said it is "an unmanaged library" and "When I use it without any managed code it works.". You can assume what that implies. **Hint**: when I say "without any managed code" I mean **no** managed code **anywhere** in the application/process.